# Laravel 5.6 and TCPDF Public Key Encryption

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, pki, laravel-5.6

I am new to PKI and was hoping someone could help me with my situation. I am currently using Laravel 5.6 to develop my site and I am using the `elibyy/tcpdf-laravel` package for creating PDF's. Currently, when my users create the PDF it is encrypted via AES 256 and password protected but I would like to add public key encryption.

Here's is the process, a contract is created via HTML, the user signs the contract, once signed a checkbox appears and a finish button. They check the box and click finish. The webpage is then converted to a PDF and stored on AWS S3.

The following is in the documentation for TCPDF about Public Key Encryption:

```
 Possible encryption modes are:
 0 = RSA 40 bit
 1 = RSA 128 bit
 2 = AES 128 bit
 3 = AES 256 bit



NOTES:
 - To create self-signed signature: openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.crt
 - To export crt to p12: openssl pkcs12 -export -in tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.p12
 - To convert pfx certificate to pem: openssl pkcs12 -in tcpdf.pfx -out tcpdf.crt -nodes

*/

$pdf->SetProtection(array('print', 'copy'), '', null, 0, null);

// Example with public-key
// To open the document you need to install the private key (tcpdf.p12) on the Acrobat Reader. The password is: 1234
//$pdf->SetProtection($permissions=array('print', 'copy'), $user_pass='', $owner_pass=null, $mode=1, $pubkeys=array(array('c' => 'file://../config/cert/tcpdf.crt', 'p' => array('print'))));

// *********************************************************
```

Question One: Where do I store the public and private keys? In my Laravel App? On AWS S3?

Question Two: Do I need to generate a public key for each contract?

Question Three: It says to open a document you have to install the private key on Acrobat Reader, I assume this is something the user would have to do in order to open the PDF?

I was hoping there was a tutorial on this, but I can't seem to find one. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Encryption, both symmetric and asymmetric, is a very fascinating topic. However, you better know it well otherwise it is very easy to create vulnerabilities that are very easy to crack.

For what you want to do, stick with symmetric encryption or even better use a PKZIP library that includes encryption. Since you mention PHP, there are a couple of zip and encrypt libraries for PHP that you will find via Google.

PKI (asymmetric encryption) is much harder to get right. For example, you want to use PKI. This means that you would encrypt your document with your private key and the customer would decrypt the document using your public key. This means that anyone can decrypt as public keys are just that public. You never disclose the private key.

Managing your public and private keys are entire services by themselves - take a look at AWS Key Management Service (KMS) and AWS Certificate Manager (ACM).

There is only one public key for each private key. These keys are mathematically related (via prime numbers) to each other.